# Run node.js script as admin / Access protected file

Tags: node.js, json, windows, file, security

I'd like to access a file that needs specific rights to open and write it. I tried:

- to convert it into a .exe file: found no working program for that
- run in elevated cmd: still no admin privileges
- WSL - Sudo command: don't work

For any suggestions about how to open a protected file please help me. (I have full access to the computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows, right?

Grant access permission for the file to the Windows user under which your nodejs program runs.

- Use an account with Administrator privilege.
- Right-click on the file or, better, its containing folder in the file explorer.
- Open the Properties box (bottom of the right-click popup).
- Open the Security tab and click the Edit button.

Then, if the user you want is in the list,  grant the extra privilege needed. If not, use the Add button.